# android : change layout screen in runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have two layout xml files. In one Layout I have RecyclerView and another layout just few textViews and button. Now my question is I want to change my layout when RecyclerView is empty. RecyclerView contains list of products which user can remove by tapping on delete icon present in each row of RecyclerView. When user reaches to size zero of list then I want to change layout to other which contains text like `your cart is empty please add some products.`

My first layout look like this.

[image]

after deleting all items from list it should look like this. My all xml file are ready.

[image]

Here is my some code of my adapter.

> onCreateViewHolder

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.checkout_single_design, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

> delete Icon Click listener

```
    holder.ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openDialog(design);
        }
    });
```

And here is openDialog() method. Here Design is my model class.

```
public void openDialog(final Design design) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Confirm");
    builder.setMessage("Remove item from cart?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            designList.remove(design);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            saveSharedPref(context, "cart", new Gson().toJson(designList));
            Toast.makeText(context, "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

> Design.java

```
public class Design implements Serializable{

    public int id;
    public String qualityId;
    public String qualityName;
    public String designId;
    public String designName;
    public String image;
    public String name; //use as shade name
    public String discPercent;
    public String amount;
    public int pcs;
    public String qty;
}
```

In activity I am just setting adapter to recyclerView.

```
co_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(CheckOutActivity.this));
co_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
adapter = new CheckOutAdapter(CheckOutActivity.this, designList);
co_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope my question is clear to all. I don't know how to achieve this. please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve that.
1) you can use a [ViewSwitcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html). It uses two layouts and you can switch them back and forth.

[Here](http://abhiandroid.com/ui/viewswitcher) is the tutorial on it.

2) you can override `setContentView` in the activity and implement your logic in it and call it from anywhere you want. Like you can set a boolean flag in it and set the layout accordingly! you don't need to restart the activity to do that.

Comment: It means I have to create a call back logic when my list is empty then use setContentView. correct?

Comment: Yes, you can check the number of items in the `RecyclerView` when the user deletes an item and then call `setContentView`if its empty but remember you will have to bind your view again whenever you call it. so if I were you I would go for `ViewSwitcher` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should to add an empty view in your layout, When the user deletes all the data from your `RecyclerView`, your `Activity` will show your view.
Here is a sample for your `MainActivity` witch contains your `RecyclerView`. Note that I'm using a `FrameLayout` for the view to stay on top of the `RecyclerView` and in the center of the screen. The empty view can be a `TextView` or a `ImageView` or whatever you want.

```
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/emptyView"
                    layout="@layout/empty_modules" />
            </FrameLayout>
```

And then, in your `MainActivity` you have to control the visibility of your `RecyclerView` when it have no data and the visibility of your `EmptyView` as well.

```
 if (your_array_data == null || your_data.isEmpty()) {

                loadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
               loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

Comment: can I change setContentView runtime

Comment: No, you can`t. setContentView( ) is called just one time. this example that I show you is the best way  to do that.